# Control done button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a view with some objects, one of them is a webview where I play a video, this view change the size and the position of the object when the device rotates. The problem occurs when I am playing the video in full screen, if I start watching the video in landscape and while I am watching the video (full screen) I rotate the device and then I hit the done button when I return to the view the objects are not in the position that they should be in that orientation.

I set the position in a function, I call that function in viewdidload and also in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation but how can I control the rotation while I am watching the video?

Comment: You need to set the positions of the objects in viewWillAppear: rather than viewDidLoad.

Comment: I used viewwillappear but that method does not get called when I return from the video thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerPlaybackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
}

- (void) playerPlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
     [self resizeSubviews];
}
```

So, when the playback finishes, you call your method to resize your subviews, and by the time the player closes, your view should look correct for the orientation.

You could also register for `MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification` instead, if that more properly fits your needs.

Comment: but I am playing the video in a webview . does this work with webview too ? thanks

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerPlaybackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.player];

Comment: that method what should i put instead name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification and object:self.player thanks

Comment: I have three webviews how do I implement this method webViewDidFinishLoad for the one I want thanks

Comment: and how would the method be after I asigned the tag ? please help as you already noticed I am a beginner :( thanks  :)

Comment: i get use of undeclared identifier MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification. how do i solve this ? thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5592/discussion-between-richard-j-ross-iii-and-alfonso)